# Is it possible to load images into UIWebView with out pointing baseUrl Bundle Url

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

I need a suggesion from you, that is In my use case I need to display the local images in to webview using html tags with out pointing base url to the [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] absoluteString];. Is it possible. If YES please suggest me a best a way to do this.

Thank you,
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly copy the images out of the bundle and into `Library/ApplicationSupport` or `Library/Caches` or even just `tmp` and point to them there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frederick, I tried it but it won't work Can you please look at my following code and suggest me if I miss any thing,NSString *absStirng=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] absoluteString];
    appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<a href='/map/'><img src="];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:absStirng];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"image.png /></a>"];

Comment: The absString local bundle path